# Make read-only column in spreadsheet using spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet

I have used [spreadsheet gem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet) to generate `xlsx`, I wants to make `read-only` for some particular columns and rows.

How to do with [spreadsheet gem](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet)?

Comment: I don't know if this is a suitable answer to your question (let me know if it is, and I'll post below), but this can be done with the `axlsx` gem: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/randym/axlsx/Axlsx/CellProtection. Note that the `spreadsheet` gem only generates `xls` files, whereas the `axlsx` generates `xlsx` files (which are more modern).

Answer (score 0):

I went through the [code](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet.git) and [documentation](https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/blob/master/excelfileformat.pdf) for the spreadsheet gem and apparently (and unfortunately) this behavior is not implemented.